# Bot crashing immediately after sending an embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

Bot was working fine, i was updating every now and then to make some new changes, i Redo'd everything i did back when it was working perfectly yet it kept crashing.

Code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'vouch',
description: "this is a vouch command!",
execute(message, args, Discord) {
    const client = message.client;
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()


    message.channel.send(newEmbed);

    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('768903864782553108')) {
        const targetID = message.mentions.users.first();

        return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        
            //.setTitle
            .setDescription(`You have vouched for **${targetID}**.`)
            .setColor('GREEN')
            .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('Bot was programmed by ~', 'https://i.gyazo.com/04b40914f14d5dba8aebb532ed3e80f3.png')
        )
    }
}
```

}

The error:

throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.description: This field is required
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users~\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users~\Desktop\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/683675132677718107/messages',
code: 50035,
httpStatus: 400
}

Comment: It shows there some error in your Embed Code.

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply do this:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'vouch',
description: "this is a vouch command!",
execute(message, args, Discord) {

if (message.member.roles.cache.has('768903864782553108')) {

        const targetID = message.mentions.users.first();
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    //.setTitle
                    .setDescription(`You have vouched for **${targetID}**.`)
                    .setColor('GREEN')
                    .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter('Bot was programmed by ~', 'https://i.gyazo.com/04b40914f14d5dba8aebb532ed3e80f3.png')

         message.channel.send(newEmbed)
          
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: and as a side note the error originated where you called a new embed but didn't give  any values for it.

```
const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()


message.channel.send(newEmbed);
```